# invalid encoding in marshaling stream: I"◄co OR [I"co]

Tags: aptana3, jrubyonrails

I have problem while coding in Jruby on Aptana framework;
 when I run the rails server, it throws "Invalid encoding in marshalling stream" 
which I don't know how to solve?

It throws an error on "<%=stylesheet_link_tag%> and <%=javascript_include_tag%>" here I give an piece of code, please help for solving this issue:

```
<title><%=content_for?(:title)?yield(:title) : "MyApp"%></title>

 <meta name="description" content="">

 <meta name="author" content="">

 <%=stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"%>

 <%=javascript_include_tag "application"%>

  <%=csrf_meta_tags%>

  <%=yield(:head)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

try running `rake tmp:clear` it's choking on MRI files -- This is a duplicate of this question  [Windows - JRuby on Rails - ActionView::Template::Error invalid encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851746/windows-jruby-on-rails-actionviewtemplateerror-invalid-encoding)