# Windows - JRuby on Rails - ActionView::Template::Error invalid encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I want to try jruby 1.7.0.RC2 on Windows with Rails 3.2. I'm able to start the server, but each time I try to access a page that requires a css (javascript_include_tag), I get the following error:

```
invalid encoding in marshaling stream: I"co
```

Here is the stack trace, if it helps:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (invalid encoding in marshaling stream: I"◄co):
    9:     = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_h
tml_haml__357561048_13162'

  Rendered C:/jruby-1.7.0.RC2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/act
ion_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (7.0ms)
  Rendered C:/jruby-1.7.0.RC2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/act
ion_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendered C:/jruby-1.7.0.RC2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/act
ion_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layo
ut (41.0ms)
```

My application.css is only the result of the default asset pipeline, nothing fancy. I even get the same error with an empty application.css.scss file...

Everything works fine with Ruby MRI 1.9.2 and 1.9.3.

I must say that when it comes to encoding, I'm clueless. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `rake tmp:clear` in the project root dir fixed this issue for me. It seems that jRuby does not like to use MRI Ruby's cached files.